# Google Web Designer: Javascript API - jump to key frame and stop

Tags: javascript, google-web-designer

We use Google Webdesigner to comforatbly create animation which later should be controlled by a custom CMS.

It [is possible to define key frames](https://support.google.com/webdesigner/answer/6065570?hl=en).

Is there a Javascript API to control the animation in a way to load it and move to a specific key frame and stop there?

We tried custom code like this:

```
function handleAdInitialized(event) { gwd.actions.timeline.pause('gwd-ad'); }
```

But it does not work have any effect.

When trying to execute the command in the browser console I get

```
 VM84:1 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'timeline' of undefined
at <anonymous>:1:13
```

**EDIT**
In Google Webdesigner I created a event "on page load" to skip to the key frame, that works, but not if I play the ad in Googel Chrome directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It actually seems to work if some events are defined in GWD, then also the javascript API is published.